# Push notifications from greengrass to AWS SNS using SNS connector

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, aws-iot-greengrass

i'm currently working in a project in which I have to send MQTT messages from AWS IoT Greengrass to an SNS Connector, and get notificated in an Android App.

I've alredy configured all related to the app, and its receiving messages exlusively when I input the custom payload for the GCM in the SNS console.

My Greengrass core is sending the MQTT Messages succesfully to the SNS connector, with the next format:

```
{
 "request": {
   "subject": "greengrassToSns",
   "message": "{
         \"notification\": {
             \"body\": \"Body of the message.\",
             \"title\": \"Title\"
               }
         }"
  },
 "message_structure": "json",
 "id" : "TestId" 
  }
```

The test console in Aws IOT when subscribing to the topic "sns/message/status" shows that the message was succesfully publish by the sns connector in the topic. However, I'm not getting the push notification.
The "message" structure, is exactly the one that GCM should use. What I think is that the SNS connector is publishing the message as a "raw" so it never knows that is payload for GCM.
Any idea of how to solve this?